# How to append options from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

I want to append an option in my select drop down. I cant make it happen. Can any one provide any explanation or right code technique to do so?? below is my code.

```js
   $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: '/api/TaskApi/' + "0",
                    type: 'GET',
         success: function (data) { //data is an array of objects
                    $.each(data,function(i,data){//data is object
                            var d = data.id;
                            var u = data.user_Name;
                            console.log(d, u);

                            $('#example-getting-started').append($('<option value = "'+ d+'">'+ u +'</option>'));
                        });


                    },

                    failure: function () {
                        alert("Failed to load Users");
                    }
                });
```

```html
   <div class="col-lg-12 spacing">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <label>Assigned To</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
                                                <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'My option'
}));
```

For adding options from a collection of items, you can do the following:

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
    $('#id').append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.value,
        text : item.text 
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change following line:

```
 $('#example-getting-started').append($('<option value = "'+ d+'">'+ u +'</option>'));
```

change it to:

```
 $('#example-getting-started').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",d).text(u));
```

Comment: then there must be something wrong in the ajax response, try to check ajax response and make sure it has data coming along

Comment: I have the ajax response and it is 200% right..  There must be some issue in this multi select drop down

Comment: I have tested this line  $('#example-getting-started').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",d).text(u)); it is working fine

Comment: look I have added a library link whihc I am using, That might be preventing it t work correctly

Comment: is it working now? or you mean your library is preventing it not to work?

Comment: I guess it is preventing it some how have a look. I even used refresh option

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$('#example-getting-started').append($('<option value = "'+ d+'">'+ u +'</option>'));
```

To this line:

```
$('#example-getting-started').append('<option value = "'+ d+'">'+ u +'</option>');
```

Lemmie know if it works.